# Why does HgCl2 react with HCO3^- but not with CO3^2-?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification, separation-techniques

I have started learning Qualitative Salt analysis recently. When I was reading about tests to distinguish $\ce{CO3^2-}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$, I came across a line in a book which states

> $\ce{HgCl2}$ forms a reddish-brown precipitate of $\ce{3HgO.HgCO3}$ with $\ce{HCO3-}$ but no reaction is reported in case of $\ce{CO3^2-}$.

I am not able to understand why there will be no reaction of $\ce{HgCl2}$ with $\ce{CO3^2-}$.

It would be better if I can get a sound logic for this so that I can remember it better.

Comment: The problem is $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ only exists in very basic solution where the predominate reaction is: $$\ce{Hg^{2+} + 2OH- <=>[aq] HgO + H2O}$$

Comment: Mercuric compounds do react with carbonate ions, but the precipitate does not contain any carbonate anion. The equation is _$$\ce{3Hg^{2+} + 2 Cl^- + 2 CO_3^{2-} -> 2 CO_2 + Hg_3O_2CO_3}$$ The precipitate $\ce{Hg_3O_2CO_3}$ is reddish brown.

Comment: @Maurice I am confused, how does the precipitate contain no carbonate ion and then you render it $\ce{Hg3O2CO3}$?

Comment: @MaxW As far as what I understand from your answer,all reactions of CO32- is accompanied by a competitive reaction with OH-.Then,why do certain reactions of CO32- occur even though they exist in very basic solution

For example: I have learnt that CO32- can react with AgNO3 to form a white precipitate of Ag2CO3.Here,why isn't Ag2O reported as the major product?Why is there a difference in product observed even though both Ag2O and HgO are both oxides that lie above the ΔG=0 reference line in the Ellingham Diagram?

Comment: @Maurice Do you mean the product is 2HgO.Hg2CO3?May I know the source from which you got this information?Any snapshot regarding this or link to an authentic source or page number of a standard book where this is mentioned would be very helpful.

Comment: Anirudh - I should have written "*My guess is that ...*". Obviously forming $\ce{HgO}$ in a carbonate solution would be a reaction of some sort. // I'd agree with your suspicion that $\ce{Hg^{2+}}$  doesn't react at all, in any way, with a carbonate solution as being wrong.

Comment: @Anirudh The formula I gave for the precipitate is $\ce{Hg_3O_2CO3}$ this can be considered as $\ce{ 2 HgO + HgCO_3}$. See Farooq's answer for a reference. I also found this data in the old Treadwell treatise "Analytical Chemistry"

Comment: @Maurice Will it exist as a double salt?

Comment: @Chem-Learner. Usually compounds like $\ce{Hg_3O_2CO_3}$ are not considered as double slt, because in the past oxides were not considered as salts. That is why they are simply described as basic salt. In the past a salt was defined as the result of a reaction between an acid and an oxide (or a hydroxide). Today a salt is often the result of an anion joined with a cation. In this cas the basic mercury carbonate may be considered as a double salt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anirudh, which book is teaching this stuff? Sorry, I can only find this discussion in 1890s and the latest in my favorite Mellor's Treatise from 1930s.

Coming to 2020:

After doing a simple acid test for carbonates, a nice safe & sound method to distinguish carbonate vs. bicarbonate salt is

(a) to react it with a neutral barium chloride solution. If the solution is turbid, carbonate is present, otherwise bicarbonate. Of course the methods fail with a mixture of the two.

(b) Sodium Carbonate-Phenolphthalein Test: phenolphthalein is turned pink by soluble carbonates and but remains colourless by soluble bicarbonates

Your textbook is not completely correct when it states that bicarbonate does not react with $\ce{HgCl2}$. For your reference from A treatise on chemistry, Volume 2
by Henry Enfield Roscoe, Carl Schorlemmer, 1913, pg 699

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to carry out test for HCO3- and CO32- when they are present as a mixture?Will CaCl2 followed by NH3 addition work?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do a acid-base titration with methyl orange as indicator. Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Oh Okay,I was given that if the white precipitate of CaCO3 is formed,then it contains HCO3- along with CO32- in my lecture notes.Can you elaborate on why the further acid-base titration is required?
I am using Concise Inorganic Chemistry authored by JD Lee 4th Edition along with my notes as my main reference.Can you suggest me any book where I can learn Inorganic chemistry with concrete logic and not just filled with reactions?

Comment: For qualitative analysis, A. I. Vogel A Textbook of Qualitative Analysis is the best https://www.amazon.com/Vogels-Qualitative-Inorganic-Analysis-7th/dp/0582218667. There is more more German book *Lehrbuch der analytischen und präparativen
anorganischen Chemie* which has a lot of good schemes for qualitative analysis. One can read relevant sections with the help of machine translation.

Comment: If you are willing to spend some money and find a lot of details, one of **best** books is Holleman and Wiberg "Inorganic Chemistry" in English. It will help you as a handy reference for life. More than > 2000 pages and highly highly detailed. It is the only book which has survived for 100 of years as a textbook from Germany.

Comment: Looked for Holleman and Wiberg "Inorganic Chemistry" in English -- Couldn't find it anywhere, even as a used book.

Comment: Check the WorldCat catalogues too see libraries near you https://www.worldcat.org/title/inorganic-chemistry/oclc/48056955. Unfortunately, out of stock on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/Holleman-Wibergs-Inorganic-Chemistry-Nils-Wiberg/dp/0123526515/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=wiberg+inorganic+chemistry&qid=1589064998&sr=8-1